# Commands to know the version of OpenSSH client and server?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

In some tutorials around the web to install OpenSSH exists the following commands:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo apt install openssh-client
```

For example for `Ubuntu Desktop` is mandatory install the Openssh's Server - and it is not necessary for `Ubuntu Server`, it is already installed - furthermore I have never installed in some distribution the Openssh's Client, but I am able to connect to some host with `ssh`.

How to know the version of each one? In [ssh(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) indicates:

```
-V' Display the version number and exit.
```

But is not clear if is for the server or client - in many tutorials has the same indication about to execute `ssh -V`, but they do not indicate explicitly if is for the server or client.

**Reason**:

I want to know the client version, because suddenly my laptop with `MacOS` can't do `ssh` for some hosts anymore (it after to did do an upgrade in the hosts `Ubuntu` from `20.04` to `22.04`), while for another laptops with Linux (as client) they can do the ssh to the same hosts yet - after to did do a research, seems it is due the client version - therefore I want to know the client versions from MacOS and Linux.

Comment: I'm assuming that both will have always the same version. Try running:
`dpkg-query --showformat='${Version}\n' --show openssh-server openssh-client`. In my case both return the same version.

Comment: It's extremely uncommon to install the OpenSSH client tools and the `sshd` service from two different releases of OpenSSH.

Comment: `dpkg - l | grep ssh`. I wonder why you even need to know the exact versions. It's not as if SSH(d) has seen major new features recently.

Comment: `ssh -vv localhost` will show both the client and server versions.

Comment: Perhaps Should I assume when `sudo apt install openssh-server` was executed, internally was installed the client too? Even if I am wrong - I want to know what is the current OpenSSH Client available.

Comment: The ssh man page says "ssh — OpenSSH remote login **client**", so `ssh -V` would obviously show the the version of the client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### for client:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

### for server:

```
$ sshd -V
unknown option -- V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

or

```
nc -w1 localhost 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 xxxx
```

Comment: I see, `ssh` is the client and `sshd` is the server

Comment: Just being curious, why `sshd -V` returns `unknown option -- v` and later the expected information?. At a first glance seems illogical

Comment: There's no -V but on unknown switch, the default behavior id to display the version number. Kind of little hack

Comment: How to know this if it fails and won't even run due to a version mismatch? ldd?